# How to use SVN commands from command line?

Tags: eclipse, svn

I am able to check out projects from SVN repository using eclipse as in the below screen shot.

[image]

But i am not able to do the same from command line..I am getting the error as :  `'SVN' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

If SVN is not installed on my machine how come eclipse is able to checkout?

Do i need to install SVN client in my machine?

I tried searching on my machine but could not find which path(SVN installation) eclipse is referring to execute SVN commands

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do with Subversion. Without any requirements, it is not possible to say if you need the command client or not. Usually, the command client is used for any automation, to include some SVN part in a script, or if you are more fluent with the command shell instead of a UI tool.

Answer (score 1):

[Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) is coming with its own [SvnClientAdapter](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnClientAdapter.html) which implements the Subversion API.

[Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html) itself provides a default UI, in the form of a command line interface. If you want to easy operate with it on the Windows console, then you should add the Subversion home to the `PATH` environment variable.

Apart from that I prefer in most cases to use [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You should install the command line client yes. For help on that see [svnbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/index.html)

Comment: If i don't have it installed from where eclipse is using?

Comment: It's probably using it's own copy of the client library, not the comand line executables.